# Disable caching magento while editing CSS and HTML files

Tags: magento

Seemingly simple question here although I can't seem to find an answer.

Developing a Magento site, and I have all the cache turned off inside the cache management tab, yet sometimes simply dumping the cache in chrome is not enough to see changes to js/css. I will have to go back into magento and dump the cache from there.

Am I not disabling the CSS/JS cache? Thanks!

Comment: Ctrl-F5 two to three times in a row to force CSS/JS reloads are quite common. Has nothing to do with the Magento cache, it's a browser cache issue.

Comment: I have an extension on chrome that dumps the cache, I click it multiple times before going into the magento cache.

Comment: You didn't mention if this was JS/CSS you're editing in external files, or if it's JS/CSS that's embedded in the page. That will make a big difference in the cause of (and answer to) your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never had issues if I:

1. `System > Cache Management`
2. Disable all cache
3. Open in chrome and `Ctrl+Shift+R`

Also, do you know if you have the setting enabled to combine CSS / JS? That could potentially cause issues. It's located in `System > Configuration > Developer`

Answer (score 0):

Try refereshing by `Ctrl+Shift+R`